# Highcharts - Standalone-adapter

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have created a Master-Detail chart, following this HighCharts API example:

[Highcharts .com demo dynamic-master-detail]

There is a JSFiddle I have setup to show this is working fine:

https://jsfiddle.net/uL36ftd9/2/

However, this example uses JQuery which I need to remove, I have managed nearly all of this, however, there is a line which creates the Detail Chart - it is called from the Callback when the Master Chart is created (Fiddle JS line 76).

```js
}).highcharts(); // return chart
```

I cannot seem to restructure the logic correctly to return a Chart instance:

I have configured another Fiddle with my attempt but cannot post it due to low rep. jsfiddle .net 1081ddwo

Is it correct, or even possible, to try to return the Chart object wherever the JQuery code is calling .highcharts();

Thanks for reading :)

Comment: Your https://jsfiddle.net/uL36ftd9/2/ code is failing because your data is not sorted on the time axis. Once I do `data = data.reverse()` I see your chart show. This appears to be working as designed without jQuery once you fix that.

Comment: Do you really need }).highcharts? Here you can see an example of making chart without this https://jsfiddle.net/uL36ftd9/3/